# Как выравнивать ширину дочерних элементов по ширене родительского?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Сейчас приходится задавать размеры фиксировано и вручную, но если главные родительский `.main` изменит свои размеры - придется подстраивать все остальные, ширину `.content` и `.textarea`

Все осложняется тем, что допустим, у `.textarea` есть padding и есть обводка со своими размерами, которые тоже могут сменится и не хочется, чтобы опять все пришлось перестраивать.

Я залил код на jsfiddle и пометил комментариями участки, которые было бы желательно сделать автоматическими.

Как лучше всего реализовать решение?

http://jsfiddle.net/dofqodzp/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/4wun9s32/ - а такой вариант подойдет?

Comment: Поломались margin`ы, но вариант вполне приемлемый, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```css
.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.body > div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 50px;
}
.avatar {   
    background: #ff9191;    
    width: 50px;
}
.content {    
    background: #df91ff;
    padding-left: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form {
    display: block;
}
.textarea {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="body">
        <div class="avatar"></div>
        <div class="content">Какой-то текст</div>
    </div>
    <form class="form">
        <textarea name="text" class="textarea" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="button">Отправить</button>
    </form>
</div>
```